# Confused by the 'write' of Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have learnt that:
 `write('test');` will print "test" on the screen,
while

```
program testpro;
var 
outfile:Text;
begin
assign(outfile, 'outfile.txt');
rewrite(outfile);
write(outfile, 'test');
end;
```

will write "test" to the file outfile.txt.

The code below try to do the operation of both printinng char to the screen and writing char to the file.

```
program doboth(input, output)
begin
  assign(input, 'infile.txt');
  assign(output, 'outfile.txt');
  reset(input);
  rewrite(output);
  procedure getcharfrominput;

  begin
  {procedure to read char one by one from infile and write the read char}
  { to out file and print on the screen in the same time}
      ...
      write(ch);         {ch is expected to be printed on the screen}
      write(output, ch); {ch is expected to be wrote to the outfile.txt}
      ...
   end;{procedure getcharfrominput}

begin
   getcharfrominput;
end;{program doboth}
```

But the result is that the read char was wrote to the outfile.txt twice while the screen did not have any output(This means that `write(ch);` also wrote the char to the file instead of the screen);

Then I change the declare of the 'input' and 'output' variable and get the code below:

```
program doboth;         {remove input output}
var input, output:text; {declare input and output here}
begin                   {the rest of the code is the same}
  assign(input, 'infile.txt');
  assign(output, 'outfile.txt');
  reset(input);
  rewrite(output);
  procedure getcharfrominput;

  begin
  {procedure to read char one by one from infile and write the read char}
  { to out file and print on the screen in the same time}
      ...
      write(ch);         {ch is expected to be printed on the screen}
      write(output, ch); {ch is expected to be wrote to the outfile.txt}
      ...
   end;{procedure getcharfrominput}

begin
   getcharfrominput;
end;{program doboth}
```

Then I got the result that I want.But I still do not know why could this problem be solved by such operation.

Comment: `Rewrite` truncates the file, and you're truncating both the input and output files in both cases. You can't read from a file that has been truncated (because it has no content). Your code currently says *Create two new files. If either exist, delete all the content. Now read from one empty file and write to the other.*, which clearly won't work as you intend The documentation for `Rewrite` says *Creates a new file and opens it*. You want to use `Reset` on the input file instead.

Comment: Thanks for your inform. It's 'reset' in my source file , I just make I mistake when write the code in this question  @KenWhite

Comment: If you want our help solving problems with your code, **post your real code**. Making it up as you go can introduce new errors (as you just commented it did) and hide the **actual** problem. Please [edit] your question and provide the **actual code you're using**.

Comment: If you don't want to write code which compiles (without `...` for example), probably nobody will want to look into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is a series of XY problems.  You should learn to use the debugger and learn to read the help (docwiki.embarcadero.com) so you understand Pascal syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I had solved the problem before the questions was posted, but I just didn't know why. I did spend time to make sure that my problem is clear enough. That's why I did not posted  the code that compiles. @user2460408

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time ago, programs used to get their input from keyboards and wrote their output to the console (text screen) or to text files.
The parameters input and output of the main program made that explicit and provided a way to 'redirect' the input and output.
I.e. you can associate text files with input and/or output. Just like Ianx86 did in his program.

So,
Readln(ch) reads from input.
Writeln(ch) writes to output.

Now, if you associate output with a text file ('redirect' it), 
Writeln(ch) and Writeln(output, ch) become the same, i.e. 
Writeln(ch) no longer writes to the console, but to the text file.

Remark:

Someone mentioned that (input, output) as parameters of the main program were ignored.
That seems to be correct.
If you replace that with (inp, outp), 
"input" and "output" can still be used as global variables, and "inp" and "outp" are undeclared identifiers.
IMHO that's a compiler bug.

Comment: It was always the case that in Turbo Pascal, the parameters to "program" were ignored and the documentation made that clear.  Iirc, the reason TP permitted these parameters was simply to avoid the program failing to compile because they were there.  I don't think a documented lack of support for something qualifies as a compiler bug, myself.

Comment: The input and output declaration systems is important on older systems like VMS that allow to bind file descriptors before the program runs. TP was x86 only, so that legacy that is/was still golden in the standards didn't matter. Specially since TP derived from UCSD Pascal and not ISO.